# Calling C++ Library from C# with C++/CLI Wrapper

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a C++ library, header of which looks like:

```
void NotMyFun(double * a, int * b);
```

The function reads from `a`, and writes to `b`. To call the library I have created a C++/CLI wrapper, where below function is defined:

```
static void MyWrapperFun(double * a, int * b)
{
    NotMyFun(a,b);
}
```

and works OK. From C# code, say, I have two managed arrays, i.e. `double[] ma` and `double[] mb`, where `ma` already holds some meaningful data, and `mb` is -meaningfully- filled when wrapper is called. Is below an OK way to call the wrapper function?

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (double* pma = ma)
    {
        fixed (int* pmb = mb)
        {
            MyWrapperNS.MyWrapperClass.MyWrapperFun(pma,pmb);
        }
    }
}
```

Are the unsafe pointers a fast way? Is any data copying involved here while passing and retrieving to/from C++/CLI wrapper? Or pointers are already pointing to a continuous memory space in C# arrays?

Besides, do I need any manual memory cleaning here? If the pointers are tied to the memory of managed C# arrays, I guess they are properly garbage collected after, but just want to be sure.

Comment: That's not a real C++/CLI wrapper. You need to expose managed types in your C++/CLI function. So that the C# function can call it. You can tell that it's no good because your C++/CLI function does nothing. That function needs to adapt the C++ interface to be a .net interface. A word of advice, don't use `unsafe` code in the C#. You simply don't need to if you get the C++/CLI right. I wonder if you need the extra layer of C++/CLI. Did you consider p/invoke?

Comment: I am trying to decrease data copy as much as possible. What you mean is I guess copying from managed arrays to unmanaged arrays in the C++/CLI wrapper but I am really dealing with huge amounts of data. That's why I am using unsafe pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I think you are over-complicating things. I'd avoid the unsafe code and skip the C++/CLI layer. I'd use a simple p/invoke declared like this:

```
[DllImport(@"mylib.dll")]
static extern void NotMyFun(double[] a, int[] b);
```

Because `double` and `int` are blittable types, no copying is necessary. The marshaller just pins the arrays for the duration of the call.